# List of all errorCode in MySQLException in io.vertx.mysqlclient

Tags: java, mysql, vert.x

Is there any source, where I can get list of all errorCode/errorMessage in MySQLException (*io.vertx.mysqlclient*)

For ex:

> 1062 is MySQL Duplicate Key

Answer (score 0):

While you asked for  vert.x codes, probably source material- MySql Error reference would help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/ There are [server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html) and [client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/client-error-reference.html) side as well as [global](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/global-error-reference.html) error codes listed there.

Also, check out https://github.com/sambrmg/mysql-error-codes/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL %s represents a String ID and %d is representing a primary key(usually) decimal.
1062 is about an identical column value as an id column or such like.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/client-error-reference.html
Get the PDF download of this page in the left column of all the error codes.
note: If you use PHP it has similar numeric error messages (just to not confuse it).
note: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/global-error-reference.html for mysql errors.

Also, I had same error code from MariaDB, and found this link useful. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-error-codes/#shared-mariadbmysql-error-codes